# get textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting text-box value in JavaScript. My text-box value is "xxxxx?000-1111". While I am trying to get this value from JavaScript function I am getting the value as [object%20HTMLDivElement].... can anyone tell me, What is the mistake I have made here.

Textbox and button, text box value is replaced from other method and shows well in page.

```
    function clDoc() {
            path = document.getElementById('val').value;
            alert(path);
            var myWindow = window.open(path, '', 'width=520,height=650');
        }

    <input type="text" id="clDoc" name="myn" value="" />
    <input type="button"  onClick="clDoc()" value="View" id="groupbtn" />
```

Javascript

```
    function clDoc() {
            path = document.getElementById('val');
            alert(path);
            var myWindow = window.open(path, '', 'width=520,height=650');
        }
```

If I tried with following I am getting alert as undefined.

```
    function clDoc() {
            path = document.getElementById('val').value;
            alert(path);
            var myWindow = window.open(path, '', 'width=520,height=650');
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare:

> ```
> path = document.getElementById('val').value;
> ```

where you get the value from the HTML Element Object and

> ```
> path = document.getElementById('val');
> ```

where you get the HTML Element Object itself.

---

> ```
> path = document.getElementById('val').value;
> ```

Now, you are getting the value property but you said that it was:

> [object HTMLDivElement]

Div elements are not text inputs. They are not user editable and don't have values.

Maybe you want to get the `innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this pluker will help

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ItrYzl9MdKn7bS7JYB9B?p=preview)

Code is

```
function clDoc() {
            path = document.getElementById('clDoc').value;
            alert(path);
            var myWindow = window.open(path, '', 'width=520,height=650');
        }
```

Comment: Yep, wrong ID was used for document.getElementByID().